# How do these Javascript functions run?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two controls in my form (among others) that run Javascript functions on some event. One of them is a input of type text and I added three Javascript functions to the `onblur` event separated by a space like this:

```
<input type="text" onBlur="func1() func2() func3()"></input>
```

The second control is a combo and to this one I added two Javascript functions to the `onchange` event separated by a semi-colon like this:

```
<select "onchange="func1(); func2()">...</select>
```

My problem is that both of them work.
As I know, the correct syntax is the one with semi-colons. Why does the one with spaces work ?

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you testing this in? It's likely that the browser is trying to "do the right thing" for you. Many browsers, IE in particular, will take a guess at what the developer's intention was when encountering non-standards compliant code.

Comment: Both Firefox 8 and IE 8 behave the same. The input works with and without semicolons, but the select works only with the semicolon. Of course, both controls run the javascript when separated with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons in JavaScript are optional. This is a good blog post to explain: https://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: I'm not sure I like this article. He is suggesting never to use semicolons and to *prepend* lines with semicolons in some special cases? I think this article is right that semicolon usage contains some FUD, but it looks like it is intentionally controversial to steer up some discussion and get traffic.